# Adding tag or assigning group when user created from profile

Tags: profile

I'm trying to create a mailing list sign-up using a custom profile (capturing a little more information about the user than the default mailing list).

I'm running Wordpress 4.7.x and Civi 4.7.x

I've managed to get the profile up and running but can't work out a nice way of assigning a tag \ group to the newly created individual.

I've had a read of [How can I assign tag when certain profiles are submitted](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3863/how-can-i-assign-tag-when-certain-profiles-are-submitted) which looks like a similar question but unfortunately CiviRules isn't an option for me (4.7 not supported) nor are Drupal Webforms.

So far the best I've managed to achieve is to add a contact source field to the profile and auto-populate \ hide the field with Javascript which doesn't feel like an ideal solution.

Any thoughts or ideas appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the the profile settings > advanced settings there is an option to "Add new contacts to a Group?". This will add contacts to the group specified when the profile form is completed.

If you are looking to give the user options on which mailing lists they wish to be part of you can create a custom field with the selections. Then create smart groups for each option to use for mailings on each area of interest.